# Creating Dynamic unordered list and appending it to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created my dynamic unordered list and trying to append it to the `div` tag. Its not getting reflected. I have written the below `JS` code

```
var mydiv= $('#itemList');
var myul=$('<ul/>');
var li1 = $('<li/>').html('<a href="#managerSearchDiv" onClick="showColleagueDetail();">'+'Varun Mehta'+'</a>'+'<span>'+ '9834562873' +'</span>');
myul.append(li1);
var li2=$('<li/>').html('Varun Mehta');
myul.append(li2);
mydiv.append(myul);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="csd" class="myClass">
<br>
    <div id="itemList">

    </div>
</div>
```

No error is coming in console and list is not getting reflected on screen.

Comment: It works fine for me: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFMXL/). Looks like you have a typo in line 3.

Answer (score 0):

put it in `document.ready` and there need quote for **Varun Mehtha**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var mydiv = $('#itemList');
        var myul = $('<ul/>');
        var li1 = $('<li/>').html('<a href="#managerSearchDiv" onClick="showColleagueDetail();">' + 'Varun Mehta:' + '</a>' + '<span>' + 9834562873 + '</span>');
        myul.append(li1);
        var li2 = $('<li/>').html('Varun Mehta');
        myul.append(li2);
        mydiv.append(myul);
    });
```